# What are the advantages and the intended use of the WSDL 2.0 to RDF mapping?

Tags: web-services, soap, rdf, wsdl-2.0

The WSDL 2.0 primer includes a Mapping to RDF and Semantic Web Section.
http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl20-primer/#adv-rdf-mapping

From the above references:

> A WSDL 2.0 document represented in RDF can be more easily extended
>   with arbitrary RDF assertions and the WSDL 2.0 information can be more
>   easily associated with arbitrary other knowledge.

The mapping is also described here.
http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl20-rdf/

> This document describes a representation of that model in the Resource
>   Description Language (RDF) and in the Web Ontology Language (OWL), and
>   a mapping procedure for transforming particular WSDL descriptions into
>   their RDF form.

So a WSDL 2.0 document can be mapped to RDF and then used in a knowledge system.

Some applications/usages could include:

- Automated RDF based WS client generators.
- Including Web Service information in an RDF backed system in a standard way.

There should be more than this. I would like to understand what applications the WSDL 2.0 to RDF mapping intends to address.

What are the intended applications of the WSDL 2.0 to RDF mapping?

And what are advantages of the WSDL 2.0 to RDF mapping in respect to other methods?

Some nice examples in a situation where the this mapping provides an advantage over other methods would be great.

Comment: A standard mapping means that it'd be easier to *query* WSDL things once they've been mapped to RDF (e.g., with a SPARQL query).

Comment: This is correct but partly similar to the second bullet in the question. What would be a good purpose for this? More standardized semantic integration?

Comment: I'd think so.  If two parties say they're aggregating RDF WSDL encodings, you've got more confidence that the same queries would work in both places, now.

Comment: Sounds reasonable and also reduces the effort to come up with a mapping. But isnt this just a different form of a UDDI? XML can be queried too.
I mean in this case the RDF mapping serves a similar purpose with UDDI not something brand new.
P.S. Thank you for your answers and contribution both.

Comment: PS. And as far as I know UDDI is not widely used, neither considered practical.

Comment: BTW, there was also [SAWSDL](https://www.w3.org/TR/sawsdl/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Semantic Web Registry for Bioinformatics](http://inb.bsc.es/BioSWR/) we used our WSDL 2.0 RDF mapping library ( [WSDL 2.0 RDF java library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl2rdf/) ) to express all the services as an OWL ontology. This simplifies the registry querying when we need to search an appropriate service (via SPARQL). Also we use annotation tracking - we can keep track what user made which annotation, so doesn't allow unauthorized users modify/delete them.

Comment: Up voted as a real world example of WSDL 2.0 RDF usage.