# How to generate WADL?

Tags: spring, rest, jersey, wadl

I have a REST api written with spring and I'm interested in generating a  WADL from that service.

I saw few posts talking about that it's built in into spring & jersey and should be available from this url (using browser in my case):

> http://< host >:8080/< Project Name >/**management**/application.wadl

in web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/management/*</url-pattern>
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = { "/management" })
public class MyConroller {
```

But I'm getting:

> HTTP Status 404
>   The requested resource is not available.

I tried following these instructions, but still not working for me:-

https://github.com/autentia/wadl-tools

(You can refer to this issue: [wadl-tools](https://github.com/autentia/wadl-tools/issues/7))

How can I enable it?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the reason for using WADL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312087/what-is-the-reason-for-using-wadl)

Comment: Hi, could you share your code with controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed using wadl-tools.

see: https://github.com/autentia/wadl-tools/issues/7

But I understood that this is an old aproch, so switched to OpenApi with swagger which looks much better:
[A 'simple' way to implement Swagger in a Spring MVC application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720090/a-simple-way-to-implement-swagger-in-a-spring-mvc-application)